# i have data in hex compressed with gzip and i need to convert it

Tags: security, gzip, converters, wireshark

i was trying to complete a challenge on olicyber.it, i was asked to obtain a flag from a conversation in tcp.

with wireshark i obtained this:
1f8b0800710360620003edd1410ac2301085e1ac3d45bc80cc34895d2b788e1084ba110b698416e9dd0d821b115d1511fe6ff30666f398e9cee9b42963310b926aebfd23abd714f162d437ae4e1aa435a2daa8182b4b967aba0e25656b4deefb8f47f8b6ff535dfdff6d3f1517e26

(im not sure if it contains the flag but it was the only packet with the data )
when i try to convert from Hex with CyberChef it tels me that is a gzip.
but when i try to gunzip it does not work.

how can i convert it?

Answer (score 0):

You have only the first hundred or so bytes of what is a larger tar.gz file. Possibly much larger. The first file, for which even the header is not complete in what was provided, is called "flag.txt".

You would need to accumulate the remaining packets after that, and then use tar to extract the files.

Comment: sorry if i disturb but im new to this. They gave me a pcap file that contains 12 packets  and they wrote: " in capture is present a little exchange of TCP packets, is in our interest the frame that contains the data send by the IP .... to the IP ..., to obtain the flag is necessary extract the bytes of this packet and analize the content".  so how can extract the data and convert it?

Comment: Make sure you know the correct order of the twelve packets, and concatenate their data contents. That should be a complete .tar.gz file that you can extract with tar.